# What does a hollow star mean in chat?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

What is the difference between the two kind of stars next to starred chat messages?

[image]

Comment: FYI, I found the (potential) dupe in seconds, typing fairly obvious keywords into the search [chat star](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=chat+star). Search is useful (usually, if you get the right keywords)  ;)

Comment: for the record, I tried "chat stars" and got nothing on the first page, and nothing in the possible questions list as I typed. I didn't think to try "colors", and "chat star" gives very different results to "chat stars" :\ But yeah, I should have keep looking :)